# Npgsql event handling and concurrency

Tags: multithreading, f#, npgsql

I would like to replace my existing event implementation with one that can process events as they come in, concurrently if necessary. Unfortunately I have never implemented any kind of concurrency before, but have to start somewhere eh?

I've been reading up on [Functional Reactive Programming](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-reactive/). Despite the relatively simple looking examples, I am confused as to how I should apply these examples into my application. In fact, I am not even sure whether this is the most suitable way to achieve concurrency here.

I would also somehow be able to leverage Task Parallel Library (TPL), since it offers thread management, then I don't need to worry too much about spawning too many threads. Sadly the examples in the above link do not contain any that use TPL.

My current code is below. I am still a newbie programmer and will need some hand-holding to get through. Apologies for the trouble. :(

```
open System
open System.Threading
open Npgsql

// This application is a Windows service. PostgreSQL sends a notice whenever a new row has been added to a table. 

// The next function processes new rows, aka tasks.
let private processTask () =
    EventLog.writeEventLog "Information" "Received new task notification."
    // Task processing yet to be implemented.

// A connection to PostgreSQL that stays open while service is running. Receives notifications.
let newNotifyConnection (host : string, username : string, password : string, database : string) = 
    let connectionString = sprintf "Host=%s;Username=%s;Password=%s;Database=%s;ContinuousProcessing=true;Keepalive=120;CommandTimeout=0" host username password database
    new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString)

let private notifyConnection = newNotifyConnection Settings.npgsqlConnection
let private listen = new NpgsqlCommand("LISTEN newtask", notifyConnection)

// Event for receiving and processing notifications.
let private onNotification (sender : obj) (e : NpgsqlNotificationEventArgs) =
    processTask()

let private notificationEventHandler = new NotificationEventHandler(onNotification)

// Run this function when service starts.
let startWorker () =
    notifyConnection.Notification.AddHandler(notificationEventHandler)
    notifyConnection.Open()
    listen.ExecuteNonQuery() |> ignore

// Run this function when service stops.
let stopWorker () =
    listen.Dispose()
    notifyConnection.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 2):

If your willing to go down the functional programming route with F# first and RX I recommend installing FSharp.Control.Reactive available from Nuget. It will make working with RX that much easier including adding more methods to the Observable module (F# by default only contains a subset here).

For me the key method in your code is below since this is what links the callback to the event source.

```
let startWorker () =
    notifyConnection.Notification.AddHandler(notificationEventHandler)
    notifyConnection.Open()
    listen.ExecuteNonQuery() |> ignore
```

The trick is to give your notifyConnection object the callback object that RX provides you bridging the worlds between the Npgsql library and the RX framework so to speak.

Something like:

```
open System
open System.Reactive.Linq

let observableCreate subscriptionFunction = Observable.Create(new Func<_, IDisposable>(subscriptionFunction))

let sourceObservable = observableCreate  (fun observer -> 
    // Your notifyConnection object will now direct all events to the observer provided
    notifyConnection.Notification.AddHandler(observer.OnNext)
    notifyConnection.Open()
    listen.ExecuteNonQuery() |> ignore
    // RX includes the CompositeDisposable class which you can also use
    { new IDisposable with 
          x.Dispose() =
              listen.Dispose()
              notifyConnection.Dispose() })

use subscription = sourceObservable.Subscribe(notifyConnectionHandler)
```

Note that the FSharp.Control.Reactive Nuget package is providing the Observable.create function. (EDIT: Its been pointed out the the Reactive package does not have a wrapper for Observable.Create so I've defined it above myself).

The above will (upon subscription - using the Subscribe() method):
- Open the connection
- Execute the query
- Create a disposable to use when the subscription is disposed.

What's more interesting is that you can chain the observable and compose it with others using the methods in the Observable module allowing you to create reactive programs. Probably wise to read up on RX if your interested in working with IEvent's/IObservable's in F#.

Comment: I'll try look into Rx within next week or so. Your practical example looks really handy for a newbie like me, thank you very much. :)

Comment: I installed FSharp.Control.Reactive package, but there is no 'create' in Observable.

Comment: Your right - looking at the GitHub code for it it's probably one of the only methods not wrapped by the library. It's relatively easy to define however. Will edit my post with the definition.